# Node.js puppeteer - Getting data without elements

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm using node.js and puppeteer to get some data. ... yet the data is rendered without row td etc elements. If I copy the outer html of the target I get it like this:

```
<pre>
    <strong>Date Filed   File        ID Code     Company Name</strong>
    <hr>
    08-24-2018   <a href="/117-index.html">ABC/A</a>      <a href="url;id=777">777</a>   Company A
    08-24-2018   <a href="/007-index.html">ABC/A</a>      <a href="url;id=612">612</a>   Company B
    08-24-2018   <a href="/750-index.html">ABC/A</a>      <a href="url;id=619">619</a>   Company C
    <hr>
</pre>
```

How can I fetch the data from those 4 columns (Column1: Date Filed, Column 2: File, Column 3: ID Code and Column 4: Company Name) ?

I've I look in the dev tool I see it like this

```
<pre>
    <strong>Date Filed File ID Code Company Name</strong>
    <hr>
    08-24-2018   
    <a href="/117-index.html">ABC/A</a>      

    <a href="url;id=777">777</a>   
    Company A 08-24-2018   
    <a href="/007-index.html">ABC/A</a>      

    <a href="url;id=612">612</a>   
    Company B 08-24-2018   
    <a href="/750-index.html">ABC/A</a>      

    <a href="url;id=619">619</a>   
    Company C
    <hr>
</pre>
```

... and when I click into it it's like:

```
<pre>
    <strong>Date Filed File ID Code Company Name</strong>
    <hr>
    08-24-2018&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   
    <a href="/117-index.html">ABC/A</a>      
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="url;id=777">777</a>   
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Company A 
    08-24-2018&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   
    <a href="/007-index.html">ABC/A</a>      
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="url;id=612">612</a>   
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Company B 
    08-24-2018&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="/750-index.html">ABC/A</a>      
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="url;id=619">619</a>   
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Company C
    <hr>
</pre>
```

When I console the number of links I get 6 .... app.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

(async function main() {
  try {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('url', {waitUntil: 'load'});

    const table = await page.waitForSelector('body table');
    const rows = await page.$$('body table pre a');
    console.log(rows.length);

    ...


  } catch (e) {
    console.log('our error', e);
  }

})();
```

But how can I fetch this data properly?

Edit: OuterHTML

```
const pre = await page.$('body table pre');
const preVal = await page.evaluate( pre => pre.outerHTML, pre );
console.log(preVal);

<pre><strong>Date Filed   File        ID Code     Company Name</strong><hr>08-24-2018   <a href="/117-index.html">ABC</a>      <a href="url;id=777">777</a>   Company A
08-24-2018   <a href="/007-index.html">ABC</a>      <a href="url;id=612">612</a>   Company B
08-24-2018   <a href="/750-index.html">ABC</a>      <a href="url;id=619">619</a>   Company C
<hr></pre>
```

Comment: You want to get rid of those nbsp things?

Comment: Yes ... but mainly also to get the data of the fields Column1: Date Filed, Column 2: File, Column 3: ID Code and Column 4: Company Name. Since they are not as normally in a table tr td I don't know how to fetch them ... Do you know how?

Comment: can you add output of `page.evaluate(()=>document.querySelector('body table pre').outerHTML)`

Comment: Yes. See the edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your first code snippet, you can extract the data using the following method:

```
const result = await page.evaluate( () =>
{
    return document.getElementsByTagName( 'pre' )[0].innerHTML.split( '<hr>' )[1].trim().split( '\n' ).map( element =>
    {
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const cells  = element.trim().split( / {2,}/ );

        cells.splice( 2, 0, parser.parseFromString( cells[1], 'text/html' ).getElementsByTagName( 'a' )[0].textContent );
        cells.splice( 4, 0, parser.parseFromString( cells[3], 'text/html' ).getElementsByTagName( 'a' )[0].textContent );

        return {
            'date_filed'   : cells[0],
            'file'         : cells[1],
            'file_text'    : cells[2],
            'id_code'      : cells[3],
            'id_code_text' : cells[4],
            'company_name' : cells[5]
        };
    });
});

console.log( result[0].date_filed );   // 08-24-2018
console.log( result[1].date_filed );   // 08-24-2018
console.log( result[2].date_filed );   // 08-24-2018

console.log( result[0].file );         // <a href="/117-index.html">ABC/A</a>
console.log( result[1].file );         // <a href="/007-index.html">ABC/A</a>
console.log( result[2].file );         // <a href="/750-index.html">ABC/A</a>

console.log( result[0].file_text );    // ABC/A
console.log( result[1].file_text );    // ABC/A
console.log( result[2].file_text );    // ABC/A

console.log( result[0].id_code );      // <a href="url;id=777">777</a>
console.log( result[1].id_code );      // <a href="url;id=612">612</a>
console.log( result[2].id_code );      // <a href="url;id=619">619</a>

console.log( result[0].id_code_text ); // 777
console.log( result[1].id_code_text ); // 612
console.log( result[2].id_code_text ); // 619

console.log( result[0].company_name ); // Company A
console.log( result[1].company_name ); // Company B
console.log( result[2].company_name ); // Company C
```

Comment: ... a minor add-on ... is it possible to add two additional output fields with the innerText of the two links?

Comment: @PhilippM Updated.